# Kafka metadata.max.age.ms vs metadata.max.idle.ms

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I would like to know the impact of setting both of these options on the Producer API.

Can someone please let me know why metadata has not expired in the Scenario-1 even when metadata.max.age.ms has elapsed.

### Scenario-1

- set metadata.max.age.ms to 10 seconds.
- Leave metadata.max.idle.ms as default of 5 minutes.
- start Kafka producer. publish some messages to
  a topic using this producer.
- shutdown the Kafka cluster.
- allow more  than 10 seconds to elapse.----> I am hoping that this would cause the  producer to automatically trigger a request to update Metadata.
- Now,try to produce a message to the topic using KafkaProducer#send from
  the producer.
- This operation returns immediately, without blocking.
- I was expecting this to block as more than 10 seconds have elapsed and
  was expecting metadata to expire based on the metadata.max.age.ms
  being set to 10 seconds.

### Scenario-2

However, if do the following, then the `KafkaProducer#send` operation blocks :

- set metadata.max.age.ms and metadata.max.idle.ms both to 10 seconds.
- start Kafka producer
- publish some messages to a topic using this producer.
- shutdown the Kafka cluster.
- allow more than 10 seconds to elapse.
- try to produce a message to the topic using KafkaProducer#send from the producer.
- This operation blocks trying to fetch metadata.

I am not sure why it blocks now, but not in the first scenario.

Comment: Did you find more insights/answers to this ? Would love to hear